# Update HTML tag in the view with Ajax dilemma

Tags: html, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to this and have no idea how it must work.

I have a partial view in a `foreach` in my view that lists all news comments for that news article.

I have a textarea with a `post` button where the user can submit further comments on this news article.

The new news article must be appended to the list, without doing a `location.reload`. I was told do use `AJAX`, not `JSON`.

Here's my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[NoCache]
public ActionResult SetCommentOnNews(int newsId, string newsComment) ??
{
  var currentUser = ZincService.GetUserForId(CurrentUser.UserId);
  ZincService.NewsService.SetCommentOnNews(newsId, newsComment, currentUser.UserId);
  return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ??
}


 <div class="news-comment-content" id="news-comment-content">
      <%  if (Model.Results != null) { 
         foreach (var newsItem in Model.Results.NewsComments) %>
      <% {  %>   
         <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/SetCommentOnNews.ascx", newsItem); %>
      <% }  %>
 </div>
```

my partial:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Zinc.Web.Areas.News.ViewModels.Home.NewsCommentsViewModel>" %> //this also not right

<div class="news-post-list-item">
  <div class="news-post-user-info-wrapper">
    <div class="avatar">
       <img width="52" height="52" alt="Avatar" src="/ThemeFiles/Base/images/User/user-avatar.png"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="who-and-when-box">
      <%: newsItem.CommentDate %>
      <br />
      <br />
      <%: ViewBag.UserName %>
    </div>        
    <div class="news-comment"><%: newsItem.NewsComment %></div>
    <div class="clear"></div> 
  </div>     
  <div class="clear"></div> 
</div> 

<div class="header">
  <h3>
      Leave a comment 
  </h3>
</div>
<div>  
  <textarea id="textareaforreply" rows="3" cols="160"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="javascript:PostNewsComment(<%: Model.News.NewsId %>);" class="button" id="post_button">Post</a>     
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function PostNewsComment(newsId) {
   $("post-button").click(function () {
       var jqxhr = $.getJSON("<%= //Url.Action("SetCommentOnNews", "Home", new { area = "News" }) %>?newsId=" + newsId + "&newsComment=" + $("#textareaforreply").text(), function (data) {
     if (data.success) {
       alert($("#textareaforreply").text());
       $('#news-comment').append($("#textareaforreply").text());
     }
   });
 }
</script>
```

The above JS is what I have and must inject `HTML` in to the list using `AJAX`?
I have NO idea how to do this. Can some one help please?

Thanks

Comment: what is happening with the current code ?

Answer (score 0):

To inject HTML into a list using AJAX I would use [Knockoutjs with templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) instead of partial views.  Knockout can be used to render the information in the browser. Views are for rendering server side, which does not jibe well with AJAX.

What do you mean when you say, "I was told do use AJAX, not JSON".   AJAX uses JSON as a method for serializing the data that is sent over the network.  Are you referring to the JQuery methods **ajax** versus **getJSON**?  **getJSON** is just a wrapper around the **ajax** method that configures it specifically to retrieve JSON using the HTTP GET verb.  Either will work fine, but ajax does give you more control in configuring the request.